# TFSbuild variables, username and schedule time

Tags: tfs, azure-devops

Is there a way in a build step to retrieve the username of the person who triggers a build in TFS2018 using the build variables?
Also is it possible to get the time the build was triggered?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are BUILD_QUEUEDBY and BUILD_REQUESTEDFOR pre-defined variables that will help you identify the user started the build. There are also BUILD_QUEUEDBYID and BUILD_REQUESTEDFORID that should return the user id for the user triggered the build (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/build-release/concepts/definitions/build/variables?tabs=batch#identity_values). 
As for the time the build started, you could either just define a custom variable and populate it in a build step, or (which is a bit trickier) use REST API to query build details about currently running build, then parse the output, which will give you build start time (https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/api/build/builds)